# Typo3 - Fluid,Flexform hiding image results in "No file reference (sys_file_reference) was found for given UID"

Tags: image, typo3, fluid, flexform

I`ve created a custom Extension, which uses

`{f:uri.image(src: '{data.flexform_backgroundImages}', treatIdAsReference: '1')}`

If I hide the image at the Backend, I receive the followind issue at the frontend: "No file reference (sys_file_reference) was found for given UID". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Before using a variable you should check if it actually has got a value. To do so, put an f:if view helper around your f:uri.image view helper and use the same variable in the condition.

```
<f:if condition="{data.flexform_backgroundImages}">
    <img src="{f:uri.image(src: '{data.flexform_backgroundImages}', treatIdAsReference: '1')}" />
</f:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. The problem is, that I just have the uid of this image (using Flexform)  and I use fluid to render. If I hide the element I receive this issue. How can put the viewhelper arround? The system directly breaks if the image is hidden. I`ve got no chance to create an f:if helper arround!?

Comment: It only breaks, if the f:uri.image view helper gets called without an image. SO you have to check for the uid and only if it exists, call the view helper. I will edit my answer to give you an example.

Comment: Your right, but thats the problem. The uid for the image exists in Flexform as long you dont delete it complete. But then the system has the uid so the if condition is true. Then fluid tried to get the Image, but it is hidden and I receive the error

Comment: Then you need to put the value of the hidden field into the condition too.

Comment: Yeah seems to be the fastes solution. I will do so. Many thanks for your answers.